# Is it possible for a feature detector such as Modernizr to break a page rendering upon script load if the page contains css transformations?

Tags: css, modernizr

**Question**

Is it possible for a feature detector such as Modernizr to break a page rendering upon script load if the page contains css transformations?

**Abstract**

I am trying to create an animation using css `transform` where an arrow is moving downwards along an invisible line. Things work great until I load the modernizr library. At this point all elements are rotated 45 degrees and stripped to a thin line (most likely the elements gets hooked to the angle of the animated arrow) like this. 
[image: The corrupt page rendering with modernizr]

If I remove the script call to modernizr the page renders correctly like this.

[image: The correct page rendering without modernizr]

The animation works flawless regardless if modernizr is loaded or not - it's only the presentation of the page that seems to break up. Modernizr as script seems to load without errors by the way - it only messes with the visual output.

**Note:** Trying these following lines of code in a snippet viewer seem to render everything as it should, but the images above proves something different. The visible texts are different from the images, but all code is identical.

The animated css looks like this (credit to Joshua MacDonald for the inspiration - https://codepen.io/JoshMac/pen/MaYEmJ).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var config = {
    elements: {
      navheader: "header",
      navheadstyle: "header h1"
    },
    identifiers: {},
    classes: {
      parallaxtop: ".parallax-1"
    }
  };

  $(function() {
    $(config.elements.navheader).data("size", "big");
  });

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > 0) {
      if ($(config.elements.navheader).data("size") === "big") {
        $(config.elements.navheader).data("size", "small");
        $(config.elements.navheadstyle).stop().animate({
            "font-size": "2.0em"
          },
          200
        );
      }
    } else {
      if ($(config.elements.navheader).data("size") === "small") {
        $(config.elements.navheader).data("size", "big");
        $(config.elements.navheadstyle).stop().animate({
            "font-size": "2.5em"
          },
          200
        );
      }
    }
  });

  (function() {
    var parallax = document.querySelectorAll(".parallax"),
      speed = 0.5;

    $(window).scroll(function() {
      [].slice.call(parallax).forEach(function(el, i) {
        var windowYOffset = window.pageYOffset,
          elBackgrounPos = "0 " + windowYOffset * speed + "px";

        el.style.backgroundPosition = elBackgrounPos;
      });
    });
  })();
});
```

```css
/*! HTML5 CSS3 Styles v1.0.0 */

html,
body,
ol,
ul,
li,
p {
  font: normal normal normal 15px/normal 'Titillium Web', 'Montserrat', 'Raleway', 'Gudea', 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: left;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), 0px 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), 0px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

body {
  background: #fff;
  color: #606060;
}

nav {
  background: rgb( 255, 255, 255);
  /* Fall-back for browsers that don't
                                    support rgba */
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
}


/* Desktop styles */

@media (min-width: 300px) {
  header nav li:first-child {
    display: none;
  }
  header.wrapper {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
  header nav ul {
    margin: 10px auto;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  }
  header nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 0 10px;
  }
  header .container h1 {
    font: normal normal normal 2.5em/normal 'Gudea', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  }
  header .container>div {
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  nav .floatright {
    /* This should be replaced with something more convenient. Mobiles don't use this - better remove it from the code stack. */
    float: right;
  }
}

header:after,
nav:after,
.floatright:after,
.arrowcontainer>div:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}


/* ============================================================
  SECTIONS
============================================================ */

section.module:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

section.module h2 {
  font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
  width: 25%;
  margin: 0 auto 40px auto;
  font-size: 2.8em;
  text-align: center;
}

section.module p {
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

section.module p:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

section.module.content {
  padding: 40px 0;
}

section.module.parallax {
  padding: 0;
  background-position: 0 0;
}

section.module.parallax h1 {
  font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 4em;
  text-align: center;
}

section.module.parallax-1 {
  background: #c0c0c0;
}

footer.module.parallax-2 {
  background: #555;
}

section.module.parallax-3 {
  background: #0000ff;
}

@media all and (min-width: 600px) {
  section.module h2 {}
  section.module p {}
  section.module.parallax {
    padding: 350px 0;
  }
  section.module.parallax h1 {}
}

@media all and (min-width: 960px) {
  section.module.parallax h1 {}
}

.arrowcontainer {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: -5em;
  text-align: center;
}

.arrowtext {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.arrow,
.arrow:before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.arrow {
  fill: none;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  top: 20%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  border-left: none;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: 1px transparent solid;
  border-bottom: 1px transparent solid;
}

.arrow:before {
  content: '';
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  top: 50%;
  border-left: none;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: 1px #000 solid;
  border-bottom: 1px #000 solid;
  /*-webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-delay: 2s;*/
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
  -ms-animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: none;
  -ms-animation-fill-mode: none;
  animation-fill-mode: none;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation-name: arrow;
  -ms-animation-name: arrow;
  animation-name: arrow;
}

@keyframes arrow {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate(40px, 40px);
    -ms-transform: translate(40px, 40px);
    transform: translate(40px, 40px);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.gisslen.net/framework/core/client/modernizr-3.5.0-custom.min.js"></script>
<header class="wrapper">
  <nav>
    <div class="container">
      <!-- Start: Navigation -->
      <div>
        <h1>Main title</h1>
        <ul>
          <li>Link 1</li>
          <li>Link 2</li>
          <li>Link 3</li>
          <li>Link 4</li>
          <li>Link 5</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- End: Navigation -->
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
<!-- Start: Page content -->
<main>
  <section class="module parallax parallax-1">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Block title</h1>
      <div class="arrowcontainer">
        <div class="arrowtext">Supportive text</div>
        <div class="arrow"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="module content">
    <a name="concept"></a>
    <div class="container">
      <h2>Block subtitle</h2>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="module content">
    <a name="news"></a>
    <div class="container">
      <h2>Block subtitle</h2>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
<!-- End: Page content -->
<!-- Start: Footer -->
<footer class="module parallax parallax-2">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="footer-bottom">
      <ul>
        <li>Link 1</li>
        <li>Link 2</li>
        <li>Link 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
<footer class="wrapper">
  Last updated span
</footer>
<!-- End: Footer -->
```

The HTML-snippet above is surrounded by these lines of code (as they shouldn't be added in the snippets texteditor).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js">
<head id="Head1">
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Testing</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
</head>
<body>
  <form name="form1" method="post" action="./" id="form1">
    <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUKMjEwNDQyMTMxMw9kFgJmD2QWAgIDD2QWAgIDDw8WAh4EVGV4dAUVcmV2aXNlZCAxNjAxLjEuMS4wMTAwZGRkfaEsWaMfAzoF2J+iiXEZuLql9BHgAUKPamIAH6P8sG0=" />
    <div>
    </div>

    The snippet above...

    <div>
      <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" value="CA0B0334" />
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I am using `modernizr-3.5.0-custom.min.js` with all features and options checked and `jquery-3.2.1.min.js` (the newest jQuery version avaliable in the snippet viewer is 2.1.1, but they work all the same in this particular matter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue your having is due to the `.arrow` class. What modernizr does is it adds classes to your html tag. These classes are meant to be used by you in CSS code, so you can add fallback styles in case a feature is unsupported in the browser.

Run the page then please inspect the html classes that are being added by modernizr in google dev tools and if you find the keyword arrow then you will find that a class is being added of the same name arrow in the html tag as you are using the same class name for your arrow. This applies all the animation classes to the html tag as well and hence it renders with the effects of the arrow animation.

In order to fix this, either change your `.arrow` class name to some other name like `.arrow-animation` or try having all the classes used in the `.arrowcontainer` to be declared as nested under the parent classes as follows:

```
.arrowcontainer .arrowtext {...}

.arrowcontainer .arrow,
.arrowcontainer .arrow:before {...}

.arrowcontainer .arrow {...}

.arrowcontainer .arrow:before {...}
```

This will fix the rendering issue your having.

Hope this explains the issue and helps you to proceed.

Happy coding :)

Comment: Are you the best or the best? :) I've been tearing my hair over this trying to understand the reason for it to happen! Thank you so much - that was exactly what was wrong! I changed .arrow to .arrowanimation and now it works as I expected. I've accepted your answer!

Comment: Glad to help out my friend. Please also if you can vote up my answer than that would be great. Happy coding.

Comment: Done deal. Appreciate your help! :)